# One hash with params populate two objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

I'have an json api where user can update a post and related details to that post. To simply the process the user just fill one hash and we are no exposing our architecture. The stuff I did here work but I would like to know if their is a better way. For me I don't know why but it smells...

```
def update
    params['blog_post'] = params.delete 'post'
    @blog_post.update_attributes blog_post_params
    update_blog_post_groups if params['blog_post']['group_ids']
    params['blog_post_details'] = params.delete 'blog_post'
    @blog_post.blog_post_details.update_attributes blog_post_details_params
    render :blog_post, status: 200
end
```

`blog_post_params` and `blog_post_details_params` are strong_parameter methods.

Comment: this might be better to post to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Looks like you have to introduce `accept_nested_attributes_for` or better form object pattern.

Comment: What Tensho said:  Investigate `accepts_nested_attributes`